# How to change the scope of a variable in a Hardhat test written in TypeScript?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, typescript

I am trying to write Hardhat tests with TypeScript and am struggling with the scope of (thus accessing) certain variables. I have provided a simplified snippet of what I am struggling with.

Below, is the example that works. Declaring and assigning `accountOne` in the same unit test I need it in. However, I need the variable in more than one test, so I need to change its scope to be accessible in more than one test. This way I can avoid having to repeat the same lines of code over and over.

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

describe("Runs unit tests with Hardhat", () => {

    it("Logs accountOne's address from Hardhat", async () => {
        const [accountOne] = await ethers.getSigners();
        console.log(accountOne.address);
    });

})
```

Below is my attempt at declaring and assigning it in the `before` hook's block of code. It didn't work because it is a local variable to that block. (I've also tried using a `beforeEach` hook to similar results.) However, I've done it this way using JavaScript, and it worked previously, so I assumed it would work with TypeScript. This logs `Cannot find name 'accountOne'.`

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

describe("Runs unit tests with Hardhat", () => {

    before(async () => {
        const [accountOne] = await ethers.getSigners();
    });

    it("Logs accountOne from Hardhat", () => {
        console.log(accountOne.address);
    });

})
```

Below, is an attempt at accessing `accountOne` in the unit test. I declared it in the `describe` block of code with a type of `Signer`, assigned it a value in the `before` hook, then used it in the unit test I needed. This is the one I am least sure about because I am declaring `accountOne` as type `Signer`, when the signers are originally created from calling `ethers.getSigners()`. This logs `Property 'address' does not exist on type 'Signer'.`

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

describe("Runs unit tests with Hardhat", () => {
    let accountOne : Signer;

    before(async () => {
        accountOne = await ethers.getSigners();
    });

    it("Logs accountOne from Hardhat", () => {
        console.log(accountOne.address);
    });
})
```

Below is my most recent attempt, in which I declared and assigned `accountOne` a value in the `describe` block, then access it in the unit test. This logs nothing to the console.

```
import { ethers } from "hardhat";
import { Signer } from "ethers";

describe("Runs unit tests with Hardhat", async () => {
    const [accountOne] = await ethers.getSigners();

    it("Logs accountOne from Hardhat", () => {
        console.log(accountOne.address);
    });
})
```

I am currently learning TypeScript, so that is where I believe the issue lies. Also, because I didn't encounter this issue when writing tests in JavaScript.

Comment: See the following projects that use Hardhat and TypeScript: [solidity-template](https://github.com/paulrberg/solidity-template) and [hifi](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi) (in particular the [protocol](https://github.com/hifi-finance/hifi/tree/main/packages/protocol) package).

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, declaring `accountOne` as type `Signer` was incorrect, and instead I declared it as `let accountOne : any` in the `describe` block, assigned a value in the `before` block, then logged it from the unit test. So it seems I gave it the wrong "type" when I declared it. Seeing as how I *have* to give it a type of the time of declaration, I assigned it the type of `any`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is old and you resolve it :)
Your declarations will work inside your statement (Describe, it, before, ...). Even you can declare outside to make the variable "global" in all the file and access in every statements, like:

```
let yourVar;

before("before", function(){
   // you can access here
})

describe("Context", function () {
   // you can access here
   it("test1", async function () {
      // you can acccess here
   }) 
})
```

In this case, the `await ethers.getSigners()` return an array of type `SignerWithAddress` type, and you can import it from hardhat-ethers with `@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers`. So, you declaration should be:

```
import type { SignerWithAddress } from "@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/signers";

let account: SignerWithAddress;
```

Hope make more clear to anyone else that will have the same question :)